# Live Memory forensics android phone

Tags: android, security, memory, analysis, computer-forensics

I was thinking, by default when you get a notification on your android phone you can see it on the notification view (top bar) the app and short content of the notification. When it's a message from for example Messenger (Facebook) You can see the Messenger app name, the senders' name + a part of the message.

Because of this, I was wondering => Does android store/load the notification content into its RAM/Memory?

If yes => than it is not secure at all as we can do some Live memory forensics and get the message history of every single app on the device

Comment: Yes, it's your memory, inside your device. The CPU has (for all intents & purposes) access to all RAM on the device, so if you want to put software on your CPU to examine the memory (such as an Android variant that supports this), what's to stop you? The point with security is more about preventing _unauthorized users_ from gaining this sort of information.

Comment: Well what i meant was, messaging app's like messanger. There you can delete a message you have sent. But if i have got that message a notification is being generated and it's content is being saved in my phone's memory. In case IF the sender deletes the message he've sent i still might be able to retrieve the content just by analysing and looking for the previous generated notifications. (Even if it is not my phone, and the messages are deleted by the sender/receiver)

Comment: Right, I mean, if you've _sent_ a message to somebody else's device, then you delete it on yours, the best you can do is to _trust_ the remote device to carry out the deletion. It has no obligation to do so, and there are multitude ways for the receiving device to grab the message & save it. For instance: You have no guarantee, when you send a message, that it is received by the "messenger" app; it could've been received by a spyware app that uses the same network interface as the "messenger" app.